# SQL: Update table where column = Multiple Values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I created an SQL query which updates a table column where another column = value

CODE:

```
Update Products Set ProductName = 'Shoes' WHERE ProductID = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

The problem is with the `ProductID`. How can I make it update the column with those ID's ?

Regards.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Replace `ProductID =` with `ProductID IN`

```
Update Products 
Set ProductName = 'Shoes' 
WHERE ProductID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Answer (score 4):

You just use "IN":

```
Update Products Set ProductName = 'Shoes' WHERE ProductID in (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
```

Answer (score 0):

Both answers above are perfectly correct however if there are a list of values in a table you want to use in your IN statement you can use a SELECT statement

```
...WHERE name IN (select name from listofnames where lastname like 'C%')
```

I find this to be more of use in a dynamic environment but thought it worth a mention.