# MySQL query to update all columns in one table from table in different database

Tags: mysql

I need to update all data from one table to an identical table (layout wise) in another database. Is this possible? so far I have tried the below (first name only although ideally I want all columns without listing them individually.)

The data I am trying to fix only effect user ids between 50 and 266

This gives me a syntax error

```
UPDATE
   foundation-restore.archive,    foundation.archive   
SET
   foundation-restore.archive.FName = foundation.archive.FName  
WHERE
   foundation-restore.archive.user_id = foundation.archive.user_id    
   AND    foundation-restore.archive.user_id > 50    
   AND    foundation-restore.archive.user_id < 266
```

Note - data is on a same layout table on a different db

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL update table based on another tables value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12394506/mysql-update-table-based-on-another-tables-value)

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: Update table where column = Multiple Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5826456/sql-update-table-where-column-multiple-values)

Comment: Not a dupe as I need data from another database

Comment: It is a bit unclear from your question, but if the database tables contain the exact same data you can do a mysqldump of the table and then restore it into the second database.

Comment: I have about 200 records that are screwed and I need to fix them from a back up database. If I try and import them back in I get a duplicate key error so thinking I can update them to keep their user  id's

Comment: I have put the query together from a similar one on stack. The error is: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Answer (score 1):

Try this  ( will work in tables of same database, most probably will not work on different database)

```
UPDATE
   foundation-restore.archive INNER JOIN  foundation.archive
ON  foundation-restore.archive.user_id = foundation.archive.user_id 
SET
   foundation-restore.archive.FName = foundation.archive.FName  
WHERE foundation-restore.archive.user_id BETWEEN  50  AND 266;
```

Comment: is it possible to update all fields without writing them out, eg SET
   foundation-restore.archive.*

Comment: I think its not possible. We need to specify column names. But that is a different issue, Have you checked if the above query works ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to copy all columns data from alternate database table to other database table in different databases.

To do this you have to do many tricks.

**This is final SQL**

```
SET @Source_Database = "your-source-database";
SET @Dest_Database = "your-destination-database";
SET @Table = "your-table";
SET @Key_Field = "key-field-of-table";
SET @SetStr = (
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(@Dest_Database,".",@Table,".",COLUMN_NAME," = ",@Source_Database,".",@Table,".",COLUMN_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@Source_Database 
  AND TABLE_NAME=@Table
  AND COLUMN_KEY<>"PRI");


set @SQLStr = CONCAT(
  "update ",@Dest_Database,".",@Table,
  " inner join ",@Source_Database,".",@Table,
  " on ",@Dest_Database,".",@Table,".",@Key_Field,
  " = ",@Source_Database,".",@Table,".",@Key_Field,
  " set ",@SetStr,
  " where ",@Dest_Database,".",@Table,".",@Key_Field ," < 10"
  );

PREPARE SQL1 FROM @SQLStr;

EXECUTE SQL1;
```

**Notice**

**1st :** we need to know all fields names and put on set clause, so you we use 
*INFORMATION_SCHEMA* table

```
SELECT 
  COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@Source_Database 
  AND TABLE_NAME=@Table
  AND COLUMN_KEY<>"PRI"
```

**2nd :** We use *group_concat* function to get all fields in single line

> GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)

and add concat function to create a scheme of SET Clause

```
set @SetStr = (
SELECT 
  GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(@Dest_Database,".",@Table,".",COLUMN_NAME," = ",@Source_Database,".",@Table,".",COLUMN_NAME))
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA=@Source_Database 
  AND TABLE_NAME=@Table
  AND COLUMN_KEY<>"PRI");
```

**3rd :** we use PREPARE and EXECUTE statements to declare an SQL String and execute it.

```
PREPARE SQL1 FROM @SQLStr;

EXECUTE SQL1;
```

Best regards.